# Compile error in a short OpenGL code: 'PFNGLBINDPROGRAMARB' : undeclared identifier

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

The short code is as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    PFNGLBINDPROGRAMARBPROC glBindProgramARB;
    glBindProgramARB=(PFNGLBINDPROGRAMARB)wglGetProcAddress("glBindProgramARB");
}
```

When I compile, I got a compile error: `error C2065: 'PFNGLBINDPROGRAMARB' : undeclared identifier.`

I have checked the header file glext.h but `PFNGLBINDPROGRAMARBPROC` is in it (Line 2922). I have no idea so post my question here for help.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I have checked the include directory settings. Other system info: Windows 7 64 bit, nVidia Geforce card with latest driver installed. If you need any other related info please ask.

It's a compile error, not a link error so it has nothing to do with the existence of the extension function glBindProgramARB (It does exist in my system, I checked using glutGetProcAddress).

I know FreeGlut and GLEW library functions can help me do the same thing. But I'm just wondering why the above code can not pass the compiler and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PFNGLBINDPROGRAMARBPROC` is defined, but `PFNGLBINDPROGRAMARB` is not. You use the first of these two in the declaration, but the second in the type cast:

```
PFNGLBINDPROGRAMARBPROC glBindProgramARB;
glBindProgramARB=(PFNGLBINDPROGRAMARB)wglGetProcAddress("glBindProgramARB");
```